# Why would image show on index and not show blade

Tags: laravel

So am trying to display an image in my view, it quite working on the index blade but not displaying on the show blade with the same code. However every other data displayed

Here is my code

```
<img src="{{asset('/blog_images/'.$post->photo )}}" style="width:300px; height:150px" alt="NO IMAGE">
```

Please note that i get the full part to the image when I 
inspect on the browser.

The code above is not the only code have tried though. I've also tried other helpers like public_path, url.

I'm thinking this might be setting issues somewhere.

Please your help would go a long way. Thank you in advance

Cheers!

Comment: where is your image located? and are your index and show views in different folders?

Comment: Thank you for your response Uzair, my image is located in a folder in the public directory and to the second question, they are on the same folder

Comment: could you try `asset('storage/blog_images/'.$post->photo )` if you have run `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: In fact that's what am using for the index, meaning I have tried it too.

Comment: Can you please add show method from controller in the question?

Comment: Can you please share what does this returns: `asset('/blog_images/'.$post->photo )`? As well I'm assuming you are getting a 404 on your image, can you share the 404 link?

Comment: @Ahsan Here is the show method  ``` public function show($id)
    {
        $blog = $this->blogRepository->find($id);
        $comments = Blogcomment::where('blog_id', $id)->get();
        if (empty($blog)) {
            Flash::error('Blog not found');

            return redirect(route('blogs.index'));
        }
        
        return view('blogs.show', compact('comments'))->with('blog', $blog);
    } ```

Comment: @ChristopheHubert Is not returning any error message, all other data from the table are displayed. As i said in the qst when i inspect in the browser it quite returns the full path to the image just that it's not displaying.

Comment: @Ahsan don't mind the variable name in what i posted... The variable name tallies just that i made a mistake typing it here the real one from my code is public function show($id)
    {
        $post = $this->blogRepository->find($id);
        $comments = Blogcomment::where('blog_id', $id)->get();
        if (empty($blog)) {
            Flash::error('Blog not found');

            return redirect(route('blogs.index'));
        }
        
        return view('blogs.show', compact('comments'))->with('post, $post);
    }

Answer (score 0):

just remove the slash. I guess it will work.
if the directory is like public/blog_images then just use blog_images.

Comment: I've done that before, didn't work. Just did it again to fulfill all righteousness, same result.

Comment: have you used  like this way ! <img src="{{asset('blog_images/'.$post->photo )}}" style="width:300px; height:150px" alt="NO IMAGE">

Comment: Thank you DipGhosh I really appreciate your time. I just did now but same result...

Answer (score 0):

use command php artisan cache:clear may be index blade file can get image from cache and second think you can try $post in your blade.

Comment: Hi navdeep, appreciate you trying to help... I cleared my cache with the code and the index still loads properly. However, I didn't get what you were trying to explain at the second part of your message.

Comment: try to print $post in your view and check what data comes in it

Comment: Yeah, I've done that navdeep singh, it actually returns all the data in db and the supposed filename saved in the db which is to be used to call the image from the public directory